# Как сделать чтоб при изменении размера окна tkinter интерфейс сдвигался вместе с границей

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Столкнулся с проблемой что если сделать окно tkinter и в нем сделать интерфейс с кнопками, текстом, entry и тому подобное, то при изменении размера окна кнопки не будут сдвигаться, например:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

на этих скриншотах видно что при увиличении окна кнопки и текст меняют свое положение, и кнопка например зашла на флажки, надо сделать так чтоб при увиличении окна кординаты интерфейса менялись

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]

Comment: Рекомендую PyQt , хотя бы посмотрите парочку быстрых уроков на YouTube по pyqt и pyqt designer, а там уже сделаете вывод - остаться в tkinter или ухолить на pyqt.

Comment: "надо сделать так чтоб при увиличении окна кординаты интерфейса менялись" - как именно менялись? Переключатели должны сдвинуться ниже, или вам просто нужно, чтобы кнопка не наезжала на переключатели? Добавьте свой код (сейчас не очевидно, как вы получили такой результат, и возможно там можно что-то быстро поправить) и хотя бы эскиз, что вам нужно чтобы происходило при расширении/сужении окна.

Comment: @insolor мне нужно чтоб если окно расширяли кнопка сдвигалась на то же место где она и была, тоисть если она была снизу влева то она там и оставалась при изминении размеров

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример реализации через grid. Суть в том, чтобы через параметр weight задать, чтобы нужные колонки/строки автоматически расширялись при увеличении размера окна. Например, для последней строки задаем `weight=1`, прилипание кнопки к левой нижней границе ячейки - получается кнопка закрепленная в левом нижнем углу окна.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

root.minsize(200, 210)

root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)

tk.Label(text="Например").grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2)
tk.Label(text="Например").grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2)
tk.Label(text="Например").grid(row=2, column=1)

check_frame = tk.Frame()
check_frame.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky="W")

tk.Checkbutton(check_frame, text="Например 1").pack()
tk.Checkbutton(check_frame, text="Например 2").pack()
tk.Checkbutton(check_frame, text="Например 3").pack()
tk.Checkbutton(check_frame, text="Например 4").pack()
tk.Checkbutton(check_frame, text="Например 5").pack()

tk.Button(text="Например").grid(row=4, column=0, sticky="SW")
root.rowconfigure(4, weight=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Окно в минимальном размере (заданном с помощью метода `minsize`):
[image: Скрин 1]

Расширенное окно:
[image: Скрин 2]

Answer (score 0):

Вы кажись вы используйте метод `.pack()`. У него довольно неоднозначное размещение виджетов. Или вы комбинируете несколько методов.

Что бы ничего не сдвигалось, пользуйтесь `.grid()` или `.place()` без `-rel(x/y/width/height)` параметров.

Про них можно посмотреть на:

https://younglinux.info/tkinter/grid

https://younglinux.info/tkinter/place

Можно вообще сделать так чтобы окошко не раздвигалось и сдвигалось, с помощью метода `window.resizable(False, False)`

Comment: Не по фиксированным! Точнее кнопка слева внизу по фикс. а остальное нет!

Comment: И кстати с pack тоже не должно быть проблем реализовать "адаптивный" интерфейс. Но в данном случае все-таки grid логичнее использовать.